# Spring File Upload - 'Required request part is not present'

Tags: java, spring, rest, postman, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to send POST request to my controller but cannot pass any parameter in any type unless I decide to use JSON. My goal is to pass a String and a file to my controller but I keep getting `Required request part 'xxx' is not present` error.

```
@RestController
public class ConfigurationController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/config")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveEnvironmentConfig(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile uploadfile){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
    }
}
```

I cannot have file here. Similarly if I try:

```
@RestController
public class ConfigurationController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/config")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveEnvironmentConfig(@RequestParam("name") String name){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
    }
}
```

same thing I cannot get name here.

I am sending request via Postman as given in following screenshot:

[image: Postman Request]

[image: Postman Request 2]

The only header tag is for Authorization. I do not have any Content-Type header, I tried to add `multipart/form-data` but did not help.

Only way I could pass String parameter is by adding to URL. So following `http://localhost:8080/SearchBox/admin/config?name=test` works but this is not what I want. I want String and File parameters in Body part.

I also tested via CURL:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization:Bearer myToken" -H "Content-Type:Multipart/form-data" http://localhost:8080/SearchBox/admin/config --data 'pwd=pwd'
curl -X POST -H "Authorization:Bearer myToken"http://localhost:8080/SearchBox/admin/config --data 'pwd=pwd'
curl -H "Authorization:Bearer myToken" -F file=@"/g123.conf" http://localhost:8080/SearchBox/admin/config
```

**Note:** I checked similar posts already but did not help
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936372/upload-file-springboot-required-request-part-file-is-not-present), [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488585/postman-required-request-part-file-is-not-present), [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101931/required-multipartfile-parameter-file-is-not-present-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: For others with a similar problem, this may be the solution you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488585/postman-required-request-part-file-is-not-present

Comment: You have to add bean multipartResolver in your addConfig in case you using spring mvc. Like this http://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I finally solved the issue and sharing my solution in case someone else may face the same problem.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ConfigurationController {

    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        return new MultipartConfigElement("");
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
    @PostMapping(value = "/config", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveEnvironmentConfig(@RequestParam("password") String password, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile submissions)
            throws AdminAuthenticationException, ConfigurationException {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me in Spring 2.0.0. In fact, adding those beans creates exactly that error. Adding none won't cause an error.

Comment: @Gokhan why do you use multipartResolver() and multipartConfigElement() method.

Comment: adding @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        return new MultipartConfigElement("");
    } and works in Spring Boot 2.1.6 thanks!

Comment: please can you share the Junit test case for this controller. I am finding difficulty in sending file as post request

Answer (score 4):

In my case the issue was that my **csv was not named** as per the string set within

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> upload(@RequestParam(value = "name") String 
name,@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file){
    // TODO check file is not null and save 
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.valueOf(200));;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Same :(

{"message":"Required String parameter 'title' is not present","status":400,"errors":["Required String parameter 'title' is not present"]}

Comment: change the parameter format for "file" from Text to File from drop down menu and select the file you wanted to upload

Comment: update the first parameter to this @RequestParam(value = "name") String 
name

Comment: I already changed the name. It seems I required Bean definition. Please see my answer. It solved my problem. Thank you for helping

Comment: or you can add spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=100Mb in applications.properties configuration file

Comment: I dont know why, but interchanging the params, i.e. putting multipart file first and string next solved the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Add Bean to Config file.

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1);
    return multipartResolver;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Really not sure what was going on but I removed the code

=======REMOVE BELOW========

```
@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    return new MultipartConfigElement("");
}

@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
```

Added below:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1 
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

And, it starting working magically! Maybe thats how it was with my spring version.

Answer (score 1):

While this was not the original poster's problem, if you found this question and none of the above solutions worked for you, check your Postman headers; if "Content-Type" header is set, this may cause the error above.

Remove the "Content-Type" header and it may resolve the issue above.

See this question for more information:

[Postman : Required request part 'file' is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488585/postman-required-request-part-file-is-not-present)

Answer (score 1):

If you still getting error, try to remove all headers from postman and drop type of file

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem of testing with webtestclient. I removed header of Content-Type. I think webtestclient will add it

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that main reason is @RequestParam("file")
there should be @RequestBody instead.

Comment: `@RequestBody @RequestParam("name")  String name`   did not work. When I try `@RequestBody String name`  name variable get following value:
`------WebKitFormBoundary6WJHhVqqZrh8qeAX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

test
------WebKitFormBoundary6WJHhVqqZrh8qeAX--
`

Comment: Upvoting this answer as through it realised the name I was expecting for my file ("file") was not matching what I was setting on Postman. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also the possibility of your request body not reaching your server if it's going through a proxy or any other intermediary that may not support multipart/form-data or even octet-stream content types. Hopefully, this can be solved with extra configuration to work this kind of requests. I can also recommend you to configure a request interceptor so you can log your request before and after your controller, this might help you getting a peek into the request parameters, payload and headers. In my case I realized that the size of my request body was 0, which help me to detect what was causing this error wasn't my spring configuration. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging) I leave a useful resource to help you with the logging interceptor which Spring has out of the box. [enter link description here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the **name attribute** of the input type file was not set as **"file"**.

```
<input type="file" class="file-input" id="fileUpload" name="file">
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case solution was missing '@EnableWebMvc' annotation on configuration

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
internal class BulkOffersUploadConfig {

    @Bean
    fun multipartResolver(): MultipartResolver {
        val multipartResolver = CommonsMultipartResolver()
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000)
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(1000)
        return multipartResolver
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Example of a multipart/form-data JMeter POST:

```
HTTP Header Manager:
Accept  */*
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------jm888
Expect  100-continue
User-Agent  jmeter/3.3
HTTP Request:
uncheck the following:
Redirect Automatically
Follow Redirects
User KeepAlive
Use multipart/form-data for POST
Browser-compatible headers
Select Body Data tab
sample of Body Data:
------------------------jm888
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="microsvc"
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "orgId": 1,
    "ResourceId": "0032ade8-cd59-45b6-8fff-299a63442474",
    "StatusId": "00d8ff46-c688-47cb-85a2-8edfaa1db9a2",
    "TypeId": "a972697e-735e-11e7-8cf7-a6006ad3dba0",
    "Id": "2a1773fe-dbb8-4510-b051-32b2ad823ea1"
}
------------------------jm888
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload"; filename="1349.xml"
Content-Type: application/xml

${__FileToString(C:\\jmeterData\\sourceData\\1349.xml,,)}
------------------------jm888--
```