# How to send data as @RequestPart in the postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I just joined a new project and I'm having trouble creating an object that has an @RequestPart annotation in the controller

Here are images of the model:
[image]

Here is the controller:

[image]

And the service:

[image]

How should I send the request to create the Deliverable object?

I tried a few ways but always get the error :
request does not contain multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/json

Thank you for your help!

EDITED:

Below are the images of the postman configuration

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
2021-09-27 10:57:11.279 ERROR 148 --- [nio-8050-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/portal-cliente-api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present] with root cause
```

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at security.innotec.portalcliente.service.impl.DeliverableServiceImpl.insert(DeliverableServiceImpl.java:78) ~[classes/:?]
at security.innotec.portalcliente.service.impl.DeliverableServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b02f851b.invoke() ~[classes/:?]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at security.innotec.portalcliente.service.impl.DeliverableServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$617be602.insert() ~[classes/:?]
at security.innotec.portalcliente.web.controllers.DeliverableController.create(DeliverableController.java:56) ~[classes/:?]
at security.innotec.portalcliente.web.controllers.DeliverableController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a4692a9a.invoke() ~[classes/:?]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at security.innotec.portalcliente.web.controllers.DeliverableController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b109d415.create() ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:57) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:54) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:86) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:210) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:74) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:77) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:210) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:86) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.java:67) [spring-boot-container-bundle-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181) [spring-boot-container-bundle-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_201]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]

Comment: Can you replace the images with code-blocks?

Comment: Is this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488585/postman-required-request-part-file-is-not-present

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the way you can do it, use this example and change it according to your scenario -

In the post man select POST operation on appropriate endpoint and then follow these steps -
[image]

1. In postman set the **header** `Content-type` to `multipart/form-data`.
   [image]
2. In the **body** section choose `form-data` and set appropriate `key` (in the example it's set to **employee**) and type should be `file`
   [image]
3. In the `value` select the **employee** input file (json), here is what my example json file looks like  -
   [image]

Then you can send the request and it should work as expected.

Here is the cURL that you can use in postman to check header and request.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8081/employee' --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=8A3EEB5DA1F992DCC5B879CBF538000D' --form 'employee=@"/C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/employee.json"'
```

Comment: Hola!

I followed the steps you said and

sent the json file with the values to create the object. 

But now gives another error:

in postman: "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",

in console: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

Comment: Did you replace the `employee` key with `deliverable` and uploaded correct deliverable json file? Also can you post stack trace here?

Comment: I have updated the question with the settings you mentioned and stacktrace. thank you

Comment: From the log I see you are not passing the `idDeliverable` in the input file (Thats why you are getting . You will need to include all the data that is required by the endpoint. Please check and correct the file and request accordingly.
Also when you use `Optional` you should use `optional.isPresent()` to check for null values and process accordignly.

Answer (score 0):

The postman part is ok it is correct whatever process you have used change is required to the cotroller side only.

What I had done in postman is as below:
[image]

In my case i was consumming one jason file, an excel file and a list of images file in my API, so what I have done is as follows:

I have just change the RequestMapping things in controller and applied this code as below:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/saveRetrofitmentCampaign", consumes = {org.springframework.http.MediaType.ALL_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<?> saveRetrofitmentCampaign(@RequestPart(value = "warrantyRetrofitmentCampaign") WarrantyRetrofitmentCampaign warrantyRetrofitmentCampaign,
                                                  @RequestPart(value = "multipartFile") MultipartFile multipartFile,
                                                  @RequestPart(value = "multipartFileList") List<MultipartFile> multipartFileList)  {
    ApiResponse apiResponse=new ApiResponse();
    try {
      apiResponse=  warrantyRetrofitmentCampaignService.saveRetrofitmentCampaign(warrantyRetrofitmentCampaign,multipartFile,multipartFileList);
      apiResponse.setMessage("retro fitment saved ");
      apiResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    }catch (Exception e){
        apiResponse.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        apiResponse.setResult(e);
        apiResponse.setMessage("retro fitment not saved");
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(apiResponse);
}
```