# @RequestPart is always null for the JSON object in java spring controller

Tags: spring, controller

```
@Secured({ "ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT", "ROLE_CUSTOMERMANAGERGROUP","ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP" })
@PostMapping(value = "/create", consumes ={ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(nickname = "SaveCompanyDetail", value = " Saves Company Detail", notes = "Saves Company Detail requires the WsDTO with the customer data.", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiBaseSiteIdParam
public String createCompanyDetail(@RequestPart(value = "companyDetails", required = false) final CompanyDetailsData dataObject,  @RequestPart(value = "companyLogo", required = false) final MultipartFile companyLogo) {
    try {
        ///getting dataObject all the time
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("createCompanyDetail :: ",ex.getMessage());
        return FAILED;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

public  class CompanyDetailsData  implements Serializable
{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String id;
private String email;
private String title;
private String phoneNumber;
```

}

Always getting null in dataObject object in the controller class.

Payload:
{
"id": "123",
"email": "string",
"phoneNumber": "string",
"title": "title test"
}

Post man :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using Curl:

> curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/create'
> --form 'companyDetails={"id": "123", "email": "string", "phoneNumber": "string", "title": "title test"}'
> --form 'companyLogo=@/path/to/image.png'
> --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'

or just specify the Content-Type in Postman, it's possible that you get null because you missed it. Your controller can consume 3 different types of params including JSON, XML, and multipart/form-date. Try to be explicit about what type of request you gonna send.

you can use this thread as reference:
[How to send data as @RequestPart in the postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343118/how-to-send-data-as-requestpart-in-the-postman)